# Cant find wordpress theme HTML to edit

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to edit the html source code of my wordpress site, I am using the plugin 'Whats the file' to determine it is woocommerce.php which is in charge of my homepage.

I can locate woocommerce.php by going to appearance>theme editor. [image]

How can I edit this as HTML, can I find the file. I am looking for something like this; [image]

Website - betterfpv.co.uk
Hosting - IONOS
Theme - NewStore/NewShop Eccommerce

Comment: Hey Dan! WordPress is built in PHP but it creates your website in the languages browsers use, namely HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The `html` content you are looking for sould be inside `woocommerce.php`?

Comment: Yes, but how do I access/edit that html content?

Comment: Some parts of code you can't change it since it's generated, but other parts you can find it inside the file you want `woocommerce.php`. Go to inspect element and see which php `function()` generates which lines of html code. And from there, you know where to add/remove elements. For example, php line `get_header()` generates outer div `<div class='site-content-contain'><div id='content'>`.

Comment: I think that makes sense, thank you very much!